# Element within an Element | Selenium using VBA

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

A parent container has 3 child containers (kind of webspace) with same name, class and other attributes. Further, each child container has 10 Elements each again with the same name, class and other attribute say E1 to E10.

I need to click on E5 of the second container using a variable to be picked from excel.

I am using

```
 E5 = cells(1,2).value
 findelementbyxpath("//*[@id='abc']/container/div[2]").findelementbyxpath(//*.[contains(text(),' " & E5 & " ')]).click
```

I can use only absolute Xpath in the form of div[1], div[2] and div[3] to locate the containers as all 3 containers are identical and are just webspace. And I need to use relative Xpath to find the target element as the value needs to be picked from excel.

Everything runs fine except selenium selecting E5 from the first container every time the program runs irrespective of choosing div[1], div[2], div[3].

*absolute Xpath of element E5 on container 2 is something like this

```html
//*[@id='abc]/container/div[2]/div/div/list/div[5]
```

I cant use this directly as I need to pick data from excel.

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the actual html/url so wie can . You say: "as the value needs to be picked from excel." Can you explain a little more?

Comment: Add the html using the snippet tool via the edit bar in [edit]. Please do not post as an image. When adding the html please also indicate the appropriate value for E5.

Comment: Thanks @siebe jongebloed I unfortunately cannot share the exact html as its an internal portal. But I was able to narrow down this issue.    Just to share -(1) using findelementbyxpath("//*[xxxxxxxx]//*[xxxxxxx]") is giving more accurate results than using findelementbyxpath("//*[xxxxxxxx]").findelementbyxpath("//*[xxxxxxxx]")

Comment: (2) div in the case of absolute xpath is unable to read a variable input.
    Robot.findelementbyxpath(“//*[@id,’abc’]/div[2]//*(contains(text(),’xxxxx’) works fine
Robot.findelementbyxpath(“//*[@id,’abc’]/div[totalqty]//*(contains(text(),’xxxxx’) doesn’t work where totalqty is a variable take from totalqty= inputbox(“pls enter the qty you want”)